# YouTube JS API returning an error that was not there before

Tags: youtube, youtube-javascript-api

Been using the YouTube JS API on my website for years: https://8wayrun.com

Starting a week or two ago, I've been getting the following warning in the console:

> Unrecognized feature: 'autoplay'.

It doesn't seem to affect anything at the moment though. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Yes, and I'm not even using autoplay & not referencing autoplay in code